# Are multimode states a product state of single mode states?

Tags: hilbert-space, photons, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

Books such as 'Quantum Theory of Light by Rodney Loudon (page 140)' and 'Quantum Optics for Beginners by Ficek and Rizda (page 43)' claim that the multimode state is nothing but a tensor product of single-mode states, but doesn't this mean that there can no be correlations between photons?

Do they actually want to mean that the 'Hilbert space' associated with a multimode state is a tensor product of Hilbert spaces associated with single-mode states and not the tensor product of the 'states' themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one particle (one photon), we can represent the mode of that particle as a superposition of different modes. With mode than one particle one can still have each of the particles represented in terms of such superpositions, but the combined state is formed by the tensor product of the states of all those particles. One can go further. The combined state can be a superposition of different tensor products of states. In this way one can get a state in which the different particles are correlated with each other.

For example, consider a Bell state:
$$ |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |0\rangle |1\rangle 
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |1\rangle |0\rangle . $$
Each term is a tensor product of two states associated with two respective particles. The modes of the states are represent by 0 and 1. They are always different for the two particles in each term. In the second term the modes of the particles are interchanged compared to those in the first term. Therefore, we have a quantum correlation between the modes of the two particles.

Answer (score -1):

An optical mode is a normalized solution of the (Maxwell) electromagnetic wave equation. An electron state is a normalized solution of the Shroedinger wave equation. A mode is a state. The concept of "state" is extended when second quantization is in the picture. In that case, mode!=state.

Rodney Loudon is always right, I find. I tend to think you mis-represented his statement. Some multimode states are products of the involved single-mode states. But some are not -- the entangled states are not.

Comment: A mode is  *not* a state. A mode can have different occupation numbers, all of which are different states of that mode (and of course linear combinations thereof).

Comment: In the language of second quantization , different occupation number is considered a different state. Otherwise, a mode is a state.

Comment: What does *"Otherwise, a mode is a state."* mean? In which context is the word "mode" used for "state"? And does it mean the same as "mode" in second quantization?

Comment: "Otherwise" refers to not considering second quantization. For an electron, a state is a normalized wavefunction. In optics, a mode is also a normalized wavefunction. So, they refer to the same thing of different particles. Second quantization hijacks the term state.